# Function for updating sheet name in gspread is not working

Tags: python, gspread

it seems that I can't update the sheet (worksheet) name,

what to do?

```
sh = gc.open('My worksheet')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
worksheet.update_title = 'my sheet'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no error, its just nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_title). You can see that `update_title` is supposed to be a function call which you call as shown below.

```
worksheet.update_title('my sheet')
```